# Inifnite render error when setting value via useState inside a useEffect only when testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I have the following simple component where I am just looking to set a value at the start.

Thus trying to set the value inside `useEffect`.

I have simplified the component to be minimal here.

As long as I try to set the value via `useState`, it throws following error.

> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to
> prevent an infinite loop.

It it not the externalFunction. Issue is with using the `useState setter` itself since even setting it to true throws same error.

Why is this an issue?

If I try to do a counter inside here, I only enter `useEffect` once when I comment out `setValid`.

But if I call setValid, I enter useEffect about 25 times before erroring.

How could I rectify this issue. I need to set this value via useState for use further down in the component. Please advice.

Code:

```
export const MyComponent = () => {
  const [valid, setValid] = React.useState(undefined);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setValid(externalFunction());
    // setValid(true); // same error
  }, []);

  return <MyComponent />;
};
```

This works fine when I run it.
The error comes from running following test.

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
const render = (props) => shallow(
    <MyComponent
        {...props}
    />
);

it('should render', () => {
    const renderedModule = render();
    expect(renderedModule).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: Use an if statement to prevent the state being set? And also put `valid` into the use effect dependency array?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes that works if I do a  === undefined check. But why do I need that check since the set should only happen once? This would be the backup plan if all else fails. Not placing valid in array cos only want this to happen once and won't be needing it to trigger again. Thus leaving it empty.

Comment: Something else could be the issue then. I cannot replicate what you see https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-cdn-ixigtt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: `shallow` - are you using Enzyme?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Updated the question. Yes using enzyme.

Answer (score 0):

The example as given does not cause a recursive render. See [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-mk06gu).

If you need to set the initial value of a state to a function return value, though, `setState` can take a function to call for its initial value:

```
export const MyComponent = () => {
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(externalFunction);
  // Or more verbosely:
  // const [valid, setValid] = useState(() => externalFunction());

  return <div>test</div>;
};
```